# UIImageView is not letting me zoom into image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, uiimageview

I'm using the following code to load an image in an image view.  But it is not letting me pinch or zoom or anything.  Any ideas how to fix it?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.myURL];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
            self.imageView.image = img;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your UIImageView within a UIScrollView and implement the zoom in and out methods.

Answer (score 2):

Lucky for you, Apple wrote an ImageScrollView class for you.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Listings/Classes_ImageScrollView_h.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Listings/Classes_ImageScrollView_m.html

You can edit out the TilingView subclass of UIImageView they use and just use a normal UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

It does not automatically let you zoom or "anything". You have to program that. Use UIGestureRecognizer to recognize the pinch gesture, or you can place it in a UIScrollView and enable zooming and/or panning.